# Falha ao conectar o banco: Connection lost to database - Firebird e aplicação Delphi

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, firebird, firebase-database, erp

Tenho um servidor com mais de sessenta bases de dados de clientes que operam atualmente com Firebird 3.0.3.32900 e uma aplicação em Delphi que é responsável por sincronizar logs de uma ponta à outra. Para exemplificar, a aplicação é responsável por encaminhar dados que são gerados no PDV (vendas, cadastros...) para a Retaguarda.

Ocorre que, algumas bases não estão tendo conexão, e caso eu tente forçar um sincronismo, a mensagem *"Falha ao conectar o banco - Connection lost to database*" é exibida. Porém, consigo acessar o banco via IBExpert e via executável de Retaguarda, sendo possível até gravar dados. Mais estranho ainda, é que para a aplicação funcionar, é preciso obrigatoriamente estabelecer conexão com o banco, o que é possível sem problemas.

Essa mensagem só acontece nessa funcionalidade de sincronizar.
Qualquer outra coisa que faça, não ocorre erro de conexão com o banco.

Tenho lidado com esse problema há uma semana. Fiz a reinstalação do Firebird (inclusive migrei do 2.1.7 para 3.0.3) e até a substituição do servidor para um novo. Fiz também `gfix` que resolveu no dia, no outro o problema voltou.

Pesquisei na internet e vi algo como o Firebird não lidar com muitas instâncias ou que a porta pode estar sendo usada por outra aplicação.

O Firebird foi instalado no modo Classic e atualmente gerencia mais de 180 conexões simultâneas. A aplicação de sincronismo apenas usa uma porta que eu defino.

Alguém teria uma ideia do que pode estar acontencedo?
Espero ter sido claro, caso precisem de mais detalhes, me pergutem.

Vou continuar a pesquisar e testar aqui.

Desde já agraço. No aguardo.

Answer (score 1):

O Classic server cria um processo separado para cada conexão do client, enquanto o "Super Server" cria somente um processo e utiliza threads  e um cache compartilhado.

Momentaneamente, você pode alterar o Firebird para trabalhar em "Super Server", visto que ele é mais eficiente para trabalhar com grandes quantidades de conexões, e alterar o "conf" do Firebird para trabalhar melhor com seu hardware.

Caso você não tenha tanto conhecimento no conf, utilize um do [IBSurgeon](https://ib-aid.com/br/optimized-firebird-configuration/)

O ideal seria você parar de conectar remotamente e criar uma aplicação em 3 camadas (cliente, middleware, database).

Comment: Links uteis: 

https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/qsg25-classic-or-super.html

https://elias.praciano.com/2016/01/quais-as-diferencas-entre-firebird-classic-super-e-superclassic/

https://ib-aid.com/br/optimized-firebird-configuration/